# Definition of variables into arrays and proper syntax

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a code here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b=0,d,f=1;
    string c, e, g;

    cout<<":"<<endl;
    cin>>a;
    string question[a];
    for(;b<a;b++)
    {
        cout<<"#"<<b+1<<":"<<endl;
        getline(cin,c);
        question[b]=c;
        cout<<":"<<endl;
        cin>>d;
        getline(cin,e);
        question[b][d+1]{e};
        for(;f<d;f++)
        {
            cout<<" #"<<f<<":"<<endl;
            getline(cin,g);
            question[b][f]=g;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This does not compile and I believe it is because the variables -that I want to define the first availabe spaces in arrays as- are seen as characters and not their values that would be defined by the user input. I'm trying to get my bearings on C++ right now; could somebody explain to me in simple terms why this does not work and how I should fix my problem?

Error:

```
Error   1   expected constant expression    12
Error   2   cannot allocate an array of constant size 0 12
Error   3   'question' : unknown size   12
Error   4   syntax error : missing ';' before '{'   21
Error   5   syntax error : missing ';' before '}'   21
Error   6   '=' : cannot convert from 'std::string' to 'char'   27
Error   7   IntelliSense: expression must have a constant value 12
Error   8   IntelliSense: expected a ';'    21  19
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post the error your compiler gives you

Comment: I'll get right onto that

Answer (score 1):

This does not compile because you're trying to make an array's size dependant on the user input, and in `c++` the array size needs to be already known at compile time. Change

```
string question[a];
```

to

```
string *question = new string[a];
```

and just before `return 0` do:

```
delete [] question;
```

Also this line:

```
question[b][d+1]{e}
```

doesn't really have sense. The first index is gonna access element `b` of the array, the second one will access element `d+1` of the string, and you're trying to do something with a string there. Strings are built of characters, not other strings. Same appplies to line `27`.

Comment: Changing question[a] took out 3 errors and I thought 2 dimensional arrays are like a table with the first [] refering to a y-like coordinate while the latter refers to a x-like coordinate. How do I make it so that my array organizes the answer choices horizontall?

Comment: If the number of answers to every question is the same (lets say `y`), you can do a 2d array with `arrayName[x][y]`. If the size isn't known, do `arrayName**` and create both the array and lines with `new`. Or - use a `std::vector`

Comment: So the asterikses would replace the [x][y]? How would I specify the [x] then? Because the x represents the question and the answers would be stored in its row

Comment: In order to answer that you should read about `pointers` in `c++` :) Or - just think about what I wrote in the main post, because the answer is there. Really - just use a `std::vector`. Google it, it's really simple.

Comment: Would defining 'const char* string1 = string2.c_str();' make string1 usable in arrays in the way that I'd like to?

Comment: If by "the way that I'd like to" you mean "the way in your code", then no.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely your attempt to have an array of strings of size `a` when `a` is not 
known at compile time.

```
cout<<"Enter the number of questions:"<<endl;
cin>>a;
string question[a];         //Creates an array for questions
```

You could use a `std::vector` of strings instead of a c-style array. A `std::vector`
allows for the size to change dynamically.

You could also allocate an array on strings on the heap, by using

```
string* question_ptr = new string[a];
```

And then calling when done with the array:

```
delete[] question_ptr ;
```

Comment: Must I add the _ptr? Because Pawel Stawarz's answer shows this without the inclusion of _ptr

Comment: @user3093536 No, I just added to clarify that it is a pointer, but you can keep the same name, or use any other valid identifier.

Answer (score 0):

C++ isn't big on variable-length arrays, so this

```
string question[a];
```

is going to be bad news.  The usual C++ idiom for that sort of thing is a `vector` or (in C++11) an `array`.